# $\lim \inf, \lim \sup$ of a sequence $A_n=\{{\frac{m}{n}} | m\in\Bbb{N} \}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

Let $A_n=\{{\frac{m}{n}} | m\in\Bbb{N} \}$,  $n\in \Bbb{N}$, where $\Bbb{N}$ are non-negative integers. How do I find $\liminf_{n\to\infty} A_n$ and $\limsup_{n\to\infty} A_n$. Developing the sequence, I would say that $\limsup$ is equal to $\Bbb{N}$. Although I can't find a formal way to develop it.

Comment: Do you mean equal to $\infty$ not $\Bbb{N}$...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, $\liminf_nA_n=\mathbb N$. That's so, because if $k\in\mathbb N$, then $k$ belongs to *every* $A_n$. On the other hand, each $A_n$ is a set of positive rational numbers. But if $q\in\mathbb Q\setminus\mathbb N$, then $q=\frac ab$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $b>1$. But then, if $\gcd(b,n)=1$, $q\notin A_n$. So, it is not true that $q\in A_n$ if $n\gg1$. In other words, $q\notin\liminf_nA_n$.

And $\limsup_nA_n=\{q\in\mathbb Q\mid q>0\}$ (every positive rational belongs to infinitely many $A_n$'s).

Comment: I am a little confused with $\limsup_nA_n=\{q\in\mathbb Q\mid q>0\}$. Why $0 \notin \limsup_nA_n $? (First since $\liminf_nA_n \subset \limsup_nA_n$ and $0 \in \liminf_nA_n $ and second $\sum 1_{A_n}(\{0\})=\infty$.Is something wrong with me

Comment: I am using the convention that $\mathbb N=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$. So, $0\notin\mathbb N$.